# apprtc and webrtc server can't be accessed remotely?

Tags: webrtc, apprtc

I'm having trouble setting up the apprtc server because I can't seem to remotely access it.  Here's what I did and what's currently happening.

I git cloned this project onto an ubuntu 16.06 server.

https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc

I followed the installation instructions.

At the moment, when I type into my browser on my windows machine any of these urls, `http://192.168.0.110:8000`, `http://192.168.0.110:8080`,    `http://localhost:8000`,  `http://localhost:8080`
,  `http://localhost:8089`, I get the an error like `This site can not be reached, connection refused` or something like that.

However, if I open up an SSH terminal and type this:

```
ssh admin@192.168.0.110
wget http://localhost:8080/
```

I get an `index.html` that has the following contents

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 *  Copyright (c) 2014 The WebRTC project authors. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 *  Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license
 *  that can be found in the LICENSE file in the root of the source
 *  tree.
-->
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="WebRTC reference app">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <meta itemprop="description" content="Video chat using the reference WebRTC application">
  <meta itemprop="image" content="/images/webrtc-icon-192x192.png">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="AppRTC">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta id="theme-color" name="theme-color" content="#1e1e1e">

  <base target="_blank">

  <title>AppRTC</title>

  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="/images/webrtc-icon-192x192.png">

  <link rel="canonical" href="">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">

</head>

<body>
  <!--
   * Keep the HTML id attributes in sync with |UI_CONSTANTS| defined in
   * appcontroller.js.
  -->
  <div id="videos">
    <video id="mini-video" autoplay playsinline muted></video>
    <video id="remote-video" autoplay playsinline></video>
    <video id="local-video" autoplay playsinline muted></video>
  </div>

  <div id="room-selection" class="hidden">
    <h1>AppRTC</h1>
    <p id="instructions">Please enter a room name.</p>
    <div>
      <div id="room-id-input-div">
... and a whoel bunch of stuff that looks promising
```

What am I doing wrong?  How do I access this apprtc server/project remotely?

Comment: Do you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Hassaan I haven't had time to revisit this exact problem. But what I was able to do was successfully follow the steps in this project to get 2 way video call working: https://github.com/shanet/WebRTC-Example . In this project, it only uses STUN servers and a Node.JS servers to establish a handshake between two computers.

Comment: Okay thank you, Let me move to above example project

Comment: If any issues, read the author's blog posts which he links to: https://shanetully.com/2014/09/a-dead-simple-webrtc-example/ .  It explains why he does what he does.  For me, simply checking out the project, and running the project worked out of the box.  And it gave me enough insight into how to extend the project.